# how to dynamically calculate the width of divs based on the number of elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have HTML structure as below in my `Vue.js` project

```
<div class="flex-container"> 
 <div class="flex-item" v-for="item in list">
  {{ item.text}} 
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-container 
{
display:flex; 
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: flex-end;
align-content: center;
}
```

What I need is if the `items` in the `list` is just 1 or 2, then `flex-item` should occupy the complete width of the container otherwise `flex-item` should have `width: 40%`

The `list` is fetched via the API so the count of items is varying

Please suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:has()` selector, or if that doesn't have enough adoption yet you could set a `data-count` property on the container and target that with

```css
[data-count="1"], [data-count="2"] { ... }
```

Comment: What should this css block `{ ... }` contain?

Comment: How can I use `:has()` in this scenario